# create panda dataframe and append values in for loop

Tags: python, list, dataframe, append

I have a list from which I would like to iterate over and create tuples in a pandas dataframe in order to imitate sliding window of size 4. What I am trying to do is:

```
tuples = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in expertsDF.iterrows():
      newlst = row['name'] 
      counter = 0
      for x in newlst:
        if counter < len(newlst) - 3:
            tuples['A'] = x
            tuples['B'] =newlst(counter+1)
            tuples['C'] =newlst(counter+2)
            tuples['D'] =newlst(counter+3)
            counter = counter + 1
```

the newlst looks like this:

```
list (var1, var2, var3....)
```

and my DataFrame should be like this:

```
     A       B      C       D
1   var1   var2   var3    var4
2   var2   var3   var4    var5
3   var3   var4   var5    var6
```

Is there a way to do that in python?

Comment: could you post a sample of your output?

Comment: the code inside the if condition is not correct, therefore I have no output. I just tried to show what I am trying to do.

Comment: ok, @345243lkj done!

Comment: sorry, what is `expertsDF.iterrows()` ?

Comment: it is from library  itertools. I used it to iterate through the initial dataframe where my values where stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this close?

```
import pandas as pd
tuples = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
newlst = "abcdefg"
i = 0
for x in newlst:
    if i < len(newlst) - 3:
        t = pd.DataFrame([[x, newlst[i + 1], newlst[i + 2], newlst[i + 3]]],
                         columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
    tuples = tuples.append(t, ignore_index=True)
    i += 1
print tuples
```

This prints:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  a  b  c  d
1  b  c  d  e
2  c  d  e  f
3  d  e  f  g
```

Answer (score 1):

How about creating the DataFrame from Series objects?

```
import pandas as pd

data_list = list(map(lambda x: 'var{}'.format(x),range(0,100)))
df = pd.Series(data_list[0:97]).to_frame(name='A')
df['B'] = pd.Series(data_list[1:98])
df['C'] = pd.Series(data_list[2:99])
df['D'] = pd.Series(data_list[3:100])

df.head()

# output
#       A     B     C     D
# 0  var0  var1  var2  var3
# 1  var1  var2  var3  var4
# 2  var2  var3  var4  var5
# 3  var3  var4  var5  var6
# 4  var4  var5  var6  var7
```